# Warning: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy! in UISearchController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, uisearchcontroller

I have an error with `UITableViewController` and "UISearchController". I did by different. I wrote `self.definesPresentationContext = true` into viewDidLoad, but I got the same error.

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Please help.

My viewDidLoad code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: allEmployeesFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "mynote", cacheName: "mynote") // both mynote
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
    fetchedResultsController?.performFetch(nil)

    self.searchController = ({
        var controllerS = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controllerS.delegate = self
        controllerS.searchBar.delegate = self
        controllerS.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controllerS.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controllerS.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controllerS.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
     //   self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controllerS.searchBar
        return controllerS
    })()
}
```

My prepareForSegue code

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            if searchPredicate == nil {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController //DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
            } else {
                let object = filteredObjects![indexPath.row] as Note
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
            }
        }
        self.searchController.active = false
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
If I made `self.definesPresentationContext = true` then I need to touch two once on back button that be return on `UITableViewController` from `SecondViewController`

Comment: `if let indexPath == self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()`

Comment: No, It got an error Brocked block

Comment: does it work if you do the same in viewDidAppear?

Comment: It works, but I need to touch two once on back button that be return on UITableViewController from SecondViewController. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "touch two once"?

Comment: I need touch two once on the back button that be to return from UIViewController (the second controller) to UITableViewController ( the first controller). If I use this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code and it works.

```
 var searchController: UISearchController!

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.dataSearchResults?.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    var searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewsNow")
    if searchController.active == true  {
        query.whereKey("nameNews", matchesRegex: searchText, modifiers: "i")
        self.tableView.reloadData() // 4 win!!!
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.dataSearchResults = results as? [PFObject]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
     println(searchText)
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController)
}

func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.dataSearchResults = nil //nil
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var object: PFObject?

    var query = PFQuery(className: "NewsNow")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var imageFile: PFFile = object!.objectForKey("imageNews") as! PFFile
        }
    }

    self.searchController = ({
        var controllerSearch = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controllerSearch.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchBar.delegate = self
        controllerSearch.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controllerSearch.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controllerSearch.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        controllerSearch.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        controllerSearch.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controllerSearch.definesPresentationContext = false  //default false
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controllerSearch.searchBar
        return controllerSearch
    })()
}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var imagePass: UIImage! // image
    var nameTextPass: String! // name
    var allTextPass: String! // all text in string
    var textURLPass: String! // url of news
    var dateTextPass: String! // data of news

    if segue.identifier == "showParse" || segue.identifier == "showDetailParse" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            if let detailController = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController {

                var currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParseTableViewCell

                imagePass = currentCell.imageViewCell.image
                detailController.image = imagePass

                nameTextPass = currentCell.labelNameText.text
                detailController.textName = nameTextPass

                allTextPass = currentCell.labelText
                detailController.textOfText = allTextPass

                // link on the news
                textURLPass = currentCell.labelURLNews
                detailController.textOfURL = textURLPass

                dateTextPass = currentCell.labelDataText.text 
                detailController.dateNewsDetail = dateTextPass

            }
        }
    }
}
```